# jquery ui dialog : triggered twice with emebedded script tag problem

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

When I load the content of /test/anycontent.php

```
<div>
    <h1>My title</h1>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//        alert("it seems that the presence of script tags is enough to trigger the problem");
    </script>
</div>
```

into jquery ui dialog, the result is buggy using the $.post method,
and clean using the load method.

Here is the test with post method

```
$("#test").click(function(e){
           $.post(url, {}, function(data){
                $(data).dialog();
            });
        });
```

And here the test with get method

```
 $("#test").click(function(e){
            $("<div></div>").load(url).dialog();
        });
```

Then my problem is that with the post method,
I will have 2 instances of ui-dialog !!
only one was expected, the other is just in the middle of the first one,
and it is empty and closed.

Do you know why ?
Do you know issues for this ?

Note:
a ticket has been set
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6887

Comment: I struggled with this for a while. The answer for me was in that jQuery bug. I needed to remove parse the scripts out of the script tags, remove them and appnend scripts directly to body.

Answer (score 0):

Your div setup  is too generic. Try using a div with an id like:

$('#someDiv').dialog() to call your dialog on.

Then on close event in dialog options:

each time just call

close: function(){

$('#someDiv').empty()

}